# Hikari connection Leakage error

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, sqldatasource, hikaricp

I have implemented Hikari connection with java configuration the code is below ,

> ```
> HikariConfig sqlConfig = new HikariConfig();
> sqlConfig.setDataSourceClassName(WebAppListener.getContextParameter(DB_DRIVER_STRING));
>                 sqlConfig.addDataSourceProperty("url", WebAppListener.getContextParameter(DB_CONNECTION_STRING));
>                 sqlConfig.addDataSourceProperty("user", WebAppListener.getContextParameter(DB_USER_NAME));
>                 sqlConfig.addDataSourceProperty("password", WebAppListener.getContextParameter(DB_PASSWORD));
>                 sqlConfig.setLeakDetectionThreshold(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
>                 sqlConfig.setValidationTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)); 
>                 sqlConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
>                 sqlConfig.setMinimumIdle(0);
>                 sqlConfig.setMaxLifetime(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2)); // 120 seconds
>
>                 sqlConfig.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)); // minutes
>                 sqlConfig.setConnectionTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5));
>                 sqlConfig.setPoolName(POOL_NAME);
>                 sqlConfig.setAutoCommit(true);
>                 sqlConfig.setInitializationFailFast(false);
>
>                 dataSource = new HikariDataSource(sqlConfig);
>
>                 sqlConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("/* ping */ SELECT 1");
>                 if (null != connection) {
>                     log.info("webAppListener.java :Hikari ::NEW Connection successful! : " + connection.hashCode());
>                 }
>                 else {
>                     connection = dataSource.getConnection();
>                 }
> ```

but when i deployed my application it give this kind of log :

```
15-Sep-2016 13:34:28.553 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-1658] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferencesThreads The web application [/HIKARI_PROJ] appears to have started a thread named [HikariConnPool housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My application is run without any interruption on development server,please help me in this i was search on internet but i don't get any solution for this.